# Kubuntu 15.10 - Session save doesn't work

Tags: kubuntu, kde, session

This machine was originally installed with Kubuntu 14.10. Then I upgraded to 15.04, and since then it fails to properly restore my previous session. I recently upgraded to Kubuntu 15.10, hoping to fix the problem, but that was not the case.

In system settings I originally had "Restore Previous Session" enabled, but that didn't work as it used to. Most applications were not restarted after a reboot. Settings within those applications were not saved either. Applications were not on the virtual desktops that they were when I shut the machine down.

I typically keep Konsole open on virtual desktop number 1. Most times now when I reboot, Konsole is closed. So I have to reopen it, open a bunch of tabs, and increase the font size for each (Ctrl+)

Dolphin is my file manager. It typically stays closed nowadays, so I have to manually restart it, place it on desktop 3, open a bunch of tabs and open the most commonly accessed directories in these.

Kate has my todo list. It typically stays closed, not open on desktop 8. If Kate is open at all after a reboot, it's an empty session. In Kate itself I see all bunch of recently opened files if I select "recently opened files", and there seems to be everything but my todo list. So I have to open it manually.

All these issues are typical, but not necessarily that way. It has a factor of randomness. Sometimes, very rarely, it works for an application. So I only need to restart and configure the others in these cases. Until I reboot.

I now switched from "restore previous session" to restoring a manually saved session. While my programs to reopen now, and mostly correct, they are all on desktop 4. Not where they were and should be, so I have to manually place them on the 'correct' virtual desktops every time I reboot.

It's bloody annoying. If someone told me about these issues with their Windows or Mac, I'd advise them to switch to a modern, reliable OS asap.

Bonus question: I have Firefox and Thunderbird launchers in my 'task manager'. Why do these two not display their respective program icons(anymore)? And how can I fix that? I did consider reinstalling their packages, but I fear losing settings and saved data.

Comment: You should move your 'bonus question' to a separate question as it isn't related to the rest.

Comment: Plasma bug: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=354724

Comment: Thanks. So it's not just me, but rather a known bug. Does anyone know whether the fixed version made it into (K)Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: In Kubuntu 16.04 I couldn't get "restore previous session" to work at all, and went to manual restore. It remembers the exact save only -- so if you say have Dolphin open and navigate to a different directory, it'll open next time in the original saved directory. Dolphin and konsole work, but vlc didn't for some reason. Saved on virtual desktops okay.